# How to use phpmailer in functions.php

Tags: wordpress, phpmailer

I'm trying to use phpmailer in functions.
I have some functions:

```
  function foo()
  {
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    ob_start();
    require("phpmailer/vendor/autoload.php");
    require __DIR__ . '/phpmailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
    require __DIR__ . '/phpmailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require __DIR__ . '/phpmailer/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
}
```

and I getting error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

Comment: In PHP `use` must be called in the global namespace.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: Aside from what @AltimusPrime said, it's fairly likely you don't want to load PHPMailer this way; WordPress already includes PHPMailer, so look up the Wordpress docs on how to use it through their official support. This does mean that you will be stuck with an older version of PHPMailer for now, but PHPMailer will be upgraded to 6.x in WordPress 5.5.